# Как правильно составить post запрос к yandex translete api через QNetworkAccessManager?

Tags: c++, qt, api

Решил попробовать Яндекс переводчик в своем проекте. Проблема в том, [нет примеров](https://cloud.yandex.ru/docs/translate/operations/translate) работы с api на с++ или qt. По этому решил сам разобраться при помощи QNetworkAccessManager, просидев весь день, понял, что пора идти сюда

```
QUrl url = QUrl("https://translate.api.cloud.yandex.net/translate/v2/translate");
QNetworkAccessManager * mgr = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

connect(mgr,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(onFinish(QNetworkReply*)));

QHttpMultiPart * http = new QHttpMultiPart(this);
QHttpPart receiptPart;
QJsonObject metaBody;

metaBody.insert("targetLanguageCode", "ru");
metaBody.insert("texts", "Hello");
metaBody.insert("folderId", "b1gdeb0pudkrac4ij1hd");

receiptPart.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
receiptPart.setRawHeader("Authorization", "Bearer LjJrImZGOkZzMy4"); // ключ изменен
receiptPart.setBody(QJsonDocument(metaBody).toJson());


http->append(receiptPart);
QNetworkReply * ans = mgr->post(QNetworkRequest(url), http);
```

В метод `onFinish` я попадаю, но вот данных в `rep` нет, даже об ошибке.

```
void MainWindow::onFinish(QNetworkReply *rep)
{
    QJsonParseError parseError;
    QJsonDocument jsonDoc;

    jsonDoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson( rep->readAll(), &parseError );

    QString str = rep->readAll();
    qDebug() << str;
}
```

Ключ хоть и не верный, но api выдает ответ:

```
{
 "code": 16,
 "message": "Token signature mismatch, Key id: ajef3df54ebijh16f737",
 "details": [
  {
   "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.RequestInfo",
   "requestId": "c2bccede-0ba7-408e-bcdc-a13facf5c978"
  }
 ]
}
```

Мой аккаунт / ключ находиться в рабочем состоянии, проверял при помощи примера на Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думается что `QHttpMultiPart` не совсем то что вам нужно.
Начиная с того что получится запрос MIME из нескольких частей разделенных boundary (сомневаюсь что на стороне сервера он будет разбираться). Вдобавок вы вставляете jwt токен в заголовок одной из mime частей, а не в заголовок запроса.

Вам надо делать обычный запрос. Примерно так

```
QNetworkAccessManager * manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
connect( manager, SIGNAL( sslErrors(QNetworkReply*,QList<QSslError>)) , SLOT( sslErrors(QNetworkReply*,QList<QSslError>))) ;
connect( manager, SIGNAL( finished( QNetworkReply* ) ), SLOT( onFinished( QNetworkReply* ) ) );    

QNetworkRequest req;
QUrl r(url);
req.setUrl(r);    req.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,"application/json");
req.setRawHeader("Authorization", QString("Bearer %1").arg(token));
req.setRawHeader("Accept","application/json");
QNetworkReply* rep = manager->post(req,"{'sourceLanguageCode':'ru','targetLanguageCode':'en','texts':['gроверка API'],'folderId':'b1gdeb0pudkrac4ij1hd'}");     
connect(rep,SIGNAL(uploadProgress(qint64,qint64)),this,SLOT(uploadProgress(qint64,qint64)));
connect(upload,SIGNAL(cancel()),rep,SIGNAL(abort()));
```

Comment: Вы правы, спасибо :)